# Change Background Color of a react tag when clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am populating list of data to in a react component

```
  <center className={Styles.rangeContainer}>
    {Object.keys(generatedRange).map((res) => (
      <span key={res} onClick={change}>
        <input
          type="radio"[enter image description here][1]
          name={res}
          id={`Range${res}`}
          keys={res}
          value={res}
        />
        <label htmlFor={res} key={res}>
          {res}
        </label>
      </span>
    ))}
  </center>
```

what i want to do is change color of the span when input field is checked

From the picture the span is the gray circle, the radio button is hidden in the span with opacity of zero, but i want to change the color of the span when the radio is clicked meaning checked

```
const change = (e) => {
setShowModal(true);
setSelectedPagesNow(e);
```

};

```
  async function setSelectedPagesNow(e) {
let pages = [];
try {
  Object.values(generatedRange[e.target.value]).forEach((ress) =>
    pages.push(ress.page_url)
  );
  await setSelectedPages(pages);
  await setCurrentImage(pages[0]);
} catch (error) {
  //catch error when label not clicked
  setShowModal(false);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide more code than this, so we can see what `change` has in it, and how best to implement this logic?

Comment: Okay , what i wanted to do is 
change the color of the background of the span when the input field is clicked. (that is checked)

Comment: Can you post your picture correctly?

Comment: i just realize , i not allowed to embed an image so its a link

Comment: Where is your change function? I'm assuming there's some state object that holds the current value of the color? How is your data set up?

Comment: const change = (e) => {
    setShowModal(true);
    setSelectedPagesNow(e);
  };

  async function setSelectedPagesNow(e) {
    let pages = [];
    try {
      Object.values(generatedRange[e.target.value]).forEach((ress) =>
        pages.push(ress.page_url)
      );
      await setSelectedPages(pages);
      await setCurrentImage(pages[0]);
    } catch (error) {
      //catch error when label not clicked
      setShowModal(false);
    }
  }